# Ubuntu + SuperCollider, how to kill scsynth

Tags: audio, jack, supercollider

I just started with SuperCollider (version 3.6.6 on 64 bit ubuntu 16.04)

When I start my server (the default one), all other streaming stops working (youtube, spotify, etc.)

Even after I quit they still do not work
I tried s.quit;, s.freeAll;, 'stop', s.killAll; closing the program etc. (various comiations of these in various order).

Additionally, I tried **ps ax | grep scsynth** and killed that pid, but the process keeps respawning constantly (even if I do not kill it, if I run **ps ax | grep scsynth** twice, I get a new pid)

Any ideas how I can free up whatever the thing is that SC has taken from my streaming platforms that they need (maybe Jack, maybe someting else, I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
killall pulseaudio
```

and now I can play youtube, spotify etc even while my supercollider server is running and playing music

Granted, I do not understand why this 'fixed' my issue. I just copied it from this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033743/no-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04-spotify-and-youtube-dont-work-either/1034813 without thinking it would work